# How to find average in this python program

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, average, mean

Doubt in Python program.

This is a program to read a file and find lines starting with "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" and extract number after that. Further we have to find the average of the same. Please show how to use for loop or while loop to find the average of the variable y.

## Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    x=line.find(':')
    y=line[x+1:]
    z=float(y)
    s=0
    t=0
    for i in z:
        s=s+i
        t=t+i
avg=s/t
print(avg)
```

Comment: OK, so you have extracted the number as a string.  Now you need to convert that string to an integer, then add that to a running sum and keep track of the number of lines.  Then you have everything you need to compute the average.  Note that you will need to remove the newline before converting to integer (for example, `line[x+1:-1]`.

Comment: the number is a float. I converted the number to a float. Then tried a for loop to add the numbers and also to count the number of lines, but each digit of the float is added separately. Thus I am getting a faulty answer.

Comment: If you put the numbers into a list, you can use `avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)`. You don't need a loop.

Comment: This is for a practice exercise. I am not supposed to use sum.

Comment: Are there other builtin functions that you are not supported to use? i mean, you could always have a loop control variable and increment it to find the sum.

Comment: You are not calling `float` in that code.  Please update to show us what you currently have.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zcakzwa/19a448416b9e7da3dc2096da72690914

Comment: @TimRoberts I have edited and posted the full code I wrote.

Comment: @ TimRoberts, barmar, rv.kvetch thank you.

Comment: Which part of this problem do you need help with? What have you figured out so far? And what is the next step you identified? On a side note, what are you trying to do with the `for i in z` loop? What are `s` and `t` for?

Comment: Initialize `s` and `t` outside the loop.  Remember you are doing exactly one number in each loop, so your `for i in z` doesn't make sense.  Just `s += z` and `t += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would declare a few variables outside of the loop, because in your current code, both `s` and `t` are re-set to `0` every loop iteration:

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
sum=0
n=0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    x=line.find(':')
    y=line[x+1:]
    z=float(y)
    sum+=z
    n+=1
avg=sum/n
print(avg)
```